# How to calculate a signature with uECC?

Tags: c, digital-signature, private-key, public-key

I've already tried to use the example in `micro-ecc/test_ecdsa.c` ([micro-ecc](https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/blob/master/test/test_ecdsa.c)). My platform is a stm32 nucleo board. I can create a key pair, but the resulting signature is 64 Bytes of zero values.

```
uint8_t private[32] = {0};
uint8_t public[64] = {0};
uint8_t hash[32] = {0};
uint8_t sig[64] = {0};
const struct uECC_Curve_t * curve = uECC_secp256r1();
uECC_make_key(public, private, curve);
memcpy(hash, public, sizeof(hash));
uECC_sign(private, hash, sizeof(hash), sig, curve);
uECC_verify(public, hash, sizeof(hash), sig, curve);
```

Maybe someone has a solution for this. Thank you very much. I run this code on a windows system.